# How to run WebSockets with Spark Framework via Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, spark-java

I've taken an Example from https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/11/08/spark-websocket-chat.html and want to deploy it as war to Tomcat to run it on web server. I've found several examples with basic request (like get, for Ex.) but such way doesn't work with web sockets.

```
public class Chat implements SparkApplication{

static Map<Session, String> userUsernameMap = new HashMap<>();
static int nextUserNumber = 1; //Used for creating the next username

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Chat().init();
}

//Sends a message from one user to all users, along with a list of current usernames
public static void broadcastMessage(String sender, String message) {
    userUsernameMap.keySet().stream().filter(Session::isOpen).forEach(session -> {
        try {
            session.getRemote().sendString(String.valueOf(new JSONObject()
                    .put("userMessage", createHtmlMessageFromSender(sender, message))
                    .put("userlist", userUsernameMap.values())
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

//Builds a HTML element with a sender-name, a message, and a timestamp,
private static String createHtmlMessageFromSender(String sender, String message) {
    return article().with(
            b(sender + " says:"),
            p(message),
            span().withClass("timestamp").withText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))
    ).render();
}

@Override
public void init() {
    String route = "/chat";
    webSocket(route, ChatWebSocketHandler.class);
}
}
```

When I run it I get

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter SparkFilter
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebSockets are only supported in the embedded server

at line `webSocket(route, ChatWebSocketHandler.class);` in `void init()` method.

If smth depends on my web.xml (i've not changed it), the list is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Messenger</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.barbarian.messenger.Chat</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If I put `new SparkFilter();` before that line (just tried) I got

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter SparkFilter
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebSockets are only supported in the embedded server

at the same line.

**Does anybody have ideas of valid running it?**

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation (at least the current one):

> WebSockets only works with the embedded Jetty server, and must be defined before regular HTTP routes......

http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#websockets

Which is why you do not see any servlet config in web.xml in the sample code (https://github.com/tipsy/spark-websocket) since the embedded Jetty container can be run directly in the main method. Also it uses the org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.* package for websocket implementation.

If you need websocket to be run on Tomcat, you might want to consider using WebSocketServlet implementation in catalina package. I've found sample codes here (even though I haven't tested it yet): https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your 2nd link was very helpful (https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774). Although it's not wired with Spark, but starts fast and works under Tomcat.
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Not a problem, I'm glad to help (I'd appreciate it that you accept my answer if it resolves the issue hehe)